# Unable to create ES mapping date field

Tags: elasticsearch, elassandra

I have a table, one column is a UDT

```
CREATE TYPE baseinfo (
    head_commission_nr text,
    internal_source text,
    internal_changed date,
);
```

ES mapping for that part of the table:

```
    "internal_changed": {
      "type": "date",
      "cql_collection": "singleton"
    }
```

Indexing fails with:

> "type": "mapper_parsing_exception", "reason": "Failed to execute
> query:null : Field "internal_changed" with type date does not match
> type timestamp", "caused_by": {   "type": "invalid_request_exception",
> "reason": "Field "internal_changed" with type date does not match
> type timestamp" }

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please share a sample record of date format in UDT. obviously date format between UDT and elasticsearch are different. are you using logstash?

Comment: Example data: { head_commission_nr : '90021', internal_source : 'C16', internal_changed : '1996-08-01' }. I am using elassandra.

Comment: how do you index data?

Comment: PUT http://10.164.0.53:9200/deviceinfo

{
  "settings" : { "keyspace" : "iot_data" },
  "mappings" : {
    "deviceinfo": {
      "properties": {
        "baseinfo": {
          "type": "nested",
          "cql_collection": "singleton",
          "cql_udt_name": "baseinfo",
          "properties": {
            "internal_changed": {
              "type": "date",
              "cql_collection": "singleton"
            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

delete the indices have been created and change the mapping like this:

```
 "internal_changed": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd ",
      "cql_collection": "singleton"
    }
```

Comment: Already tried that, this returns the same error as above:     "caused_by": {
      "type": "invalid_request_exception",
      "reason": "Field \"internal_changed\" with type date does not match type timestamp"
    }

Comment: @AlexTbk are you check via _mapping or _template?

Comment: Im sending the exact PUT query as in my last comment on the question above, with the added "format" field

Comment: please check the mapping is applied? via XGET 10.164.0.53:9200/deviceinfo/_mapping

Comment: The mapping is not applied. Bad request. I helped myself for now by converting the field to a Long - Date().getMillisSinceEpoch()